# How to save the current time of the audio when it is played

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to play the audio from a specific time whenever the user plays the audio, So, I wanted to save the current time of play while the audio is being played.

I have the HTML set up in this way.

```
<audio id="track" src="/api/streamer/stream"
       ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime) + ' / ' + Math.floor(this.duration);">
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>
<span id="tracktime">0 / 0</span>
```

I can set the current time of the audio as:

```
var audioElement = document.getElementById('track');
audioElement.currentTime = 226;
```

My question is in what event would it be efficient to save the current time of the audio? One possible event would be when the user pauses the audio.

I wanted to save that time and update the database and wanted to start from the same time when users open the audio on multiple devices or browsers.

Comment: The `pause` and `ended` events are probably the two main ones you should bind this to. And if you want to also store the current position when the user leaves the page, then you probably want to send a tracing request on `visibilitychange`/`pagehide` as well, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event#usage_notes Would make sense to use the Beacon API then instead of normal AJAX or fetch for the latter.

Comment: what about when the user browses the different pages?  or select different audio from the list or user close the tab?

Comment: Please check the link I posted, and follow up on the details of what it talks about a bit. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event would have already told you, _"This event fires with a visibilityState of hidden when a user navigates to a new page, switches tabs, closes the tab, minimizes or closes the browser, or, on mobile, switches from the browser to a different app."_ - which should cover most relevant cases already.

Comment: _"or select different audio from the list"_ - what list? If you are talking about anything you implemented yourself to change the audio source, then you should know where that happens and therefor where to add the functionality to track this as well.

Comment: @CBroe found something interesting about beacon API here, https://volument.com/blog/sendbeacon-is-broken